# Swift: Background DispatchQueue thread is too slow

Tags: ios

I have a `DispatchQueue.global().async` thread running which is doing a lot of time-consuming CoreData work.

I know it's bad practice to have it like this.

Nevertheless, when I moved all this heavy computational work back there, the app got about twice as slow.

I'm assuming that's because the async task doesn't get all the resources allocated to it. Is there a way to make it be as fast as the main thread?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the task you are sending to the queue?

Comment: It's lots and lots of code to search through a massive CoreData-stored library of quotes, for specific words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try experimenting with the "qos" optional parameter on DispatchQueue.global(). However, if you have something continually running rather than exiting after its task is finished, it's better to just spawn an NSThread instead of using the global dispatch queue.

Comment: Could you please explain how I could use qos to make it run faster? Based on reading the documentation, it looks like setting the qos to `.userInitiated` is what you are referring to?

Comment: The higher the QoS is, the more resources the OS will spend on it. This will make it faster, although it'll also make it drain the battery faster.